# Disable Steam notifications in-game only

Tags: steam

Is it possible to disable Steam notifications (friend logs in, messages you, et cetera) in-game, and do so without disabling the community completely? That is to say I can still access Steam in-game - it just does not display the messages.

Emphasis that this is for in-game only, I don't want to just disable those notifications everywhere nor do I want to have to turn them on and off before and after I play a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go in-game and do shift+tab, you get that odd overlay menu.
in the friends pop-out there is your name, and a settings symbol next to it.

[image: overlay menu]

click it and you get a "friends light settings" menu

go to the Notification tab and uncheck everything

[image: friends list settings]

Comment: +1 Still not exactly what I want, but it's an improvement over what's existed before. I'll need to check this out next time I'm playing, since I didn't realize Steam added this.

Comment: As of today, this is the only answer that matches the current Steam UI.

Answer (score 9):

It would appear that there is no way of disabling notifications in-game only, while still keeping the steam community enabled in-game.

Either notifications need to be turned off globally (View -> Settings -> Friends -> Uncheck all the "Display a Notification" check boxes), or the [steam community needs to be disabled in-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/24675/8350) in order to prevent me from receiving notifications in-game.

Comment: On Linux at least, disabling the steam overlay doesn't disable the notifications.

Comment: Nor on other platforms, according to some messages in [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=760223).

Comment: Hmmmm First link seems to point back here?

Comment: @Basic It used to point to an answer, but that answer is now deleted. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 3):

View → Settings → In-Game → Enable Steam Community In-Game (remove tick)

Comment: That disables the community as whole, not just notifications.

Comment: @Wipqozn While there's nothing that does exactly what you need, other people with the same problem might be okay with the tradeoff of disabling overlay at all.

Comment: Yeah I agree, which is why I mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your status in chat to busy or away and this should eliminate notifications during game.