# Can I disable the Steam Community notification in Big Picture Mode with PS4 controller playing Diablo 2

Tags: steam, controllers, diablo-ii, windows

I decided to try Steam because it has a nice controller mapping feature to Big Picture Mode.

So what I did:

1. Mapped the keys to PS4 controller for Diablo II config
2. Enabled Steam Overlay *(in both the global and game settings, this has to be enabled for the controller to work at all)*
3. Open Big Picture Mode
4. Run Diablo II
5. Game works perfectly using the PS4 controller until I get a HUD notification

> Press Shift + Tab to access community

This happens about 30 seconds into the gameplay... my controller suddenly stops responding; I then have to use my mouse to quit the game and try again.

If somehow I could disable that notification, I think this would work perfectly.

Has anyone had a similar issue or maybe some insight?

It is so frustrating because **it works**, but the notification disables it.

A part of me thinks being on a Mac could be an issue, but for those of you that don't know, Blizzard released a Mac version of Diablo 2 and it essentially works the same as the `.exe` on Windows.

You can even pass command line arguments; I've tried to run a couple of them (through Steam) `Diablo II -glide` and `Diablo II -w` and it doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: Any specific reason you are tied to Steam? You can use something like [Joystick Mapper](https://alternativeto.net/software/joystick-mapper/) and avoid Steam altogether.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No reason. I am not tied to Steam. It was the only software that I knew about that could do this. I'll give Joystick Mapper a try! Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try it tonight and let you know how it works out!

Comment: Nice, definitely let me know! I was going to recommend xPadder but then I saw the `macos` tag but that link I sent also has other recommendations to try. I thought I was finally done with D2 but the idea of using a controller for such an amazing hack-n-slash game could get me to fire it back up, lol. I guess it's true that you can never really quite that game, you just take extended breaks :)

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sorry! I didn't get a change to work on this last night. I did notice that software is in the app store

Comment: Oh no sweat, I was just being curious

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

First involves turning steam community off (ref: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/24676/1770):

> Either notifications need to be turned off globally (View -> Settings -> Friends -> Uncheck all the "Display a Notification" check boxes), or the steam community needs to be disabled in-game in order to prevent me from receiving notifications in-game.

The second option is to install DS4Windows (http://ds4windows.com/) and play with button mappings to see if you can map "Shift + Tab" to the controller