# How can I stop getting notifications when my friends start games?

Tags: steam

Like the question [disable Steam notifications in-game only](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24219/disable-steam-notifications-in-game-only) is there a way to stop getting a popup when a friend starts playing a game?

---

I tried following the global method as outlined above, as that is what I want:

> Either notifications need to be turned off globally (View -> Settings -> Friends -> Uncheck all the "Display a Notification" check boxes)

However I can't see the 'Friends' tab.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you:

- Open "Friends & Chat".
- Click on the cog in the bottom left corner of your profile box.
- Go to the notifications page.
- Untick the boxes you don't want notifications about.
  For the question it was the boxes next to "when a friend joins a game".